# How to get my younger dog to stop pestering my older dog?

Tags: dogs, behavior, play, senior-pet, herding

My older dog is an overly-tolerant purebred Newfoundland(True). She and my younger dog have lived together in the same house since we adopted the younger one at 5 months old. The Newfie is seven years old now, and is getting quite tired of my rescue mix's pestering. My rescue mix(Luna) is three, and she still tries to get my Newfie girl to play. When True refuses to play with Luna, Luna tries to herd her. True just sits there. This frustrates Luna, so she tries to use True's neck fur to pull her out of a sitting position. Eventually, True gets tired of this, and gently but clearly exerts dominance. Luna backs off, but only for 5-25 minutes, at which point she begins again. True has been at a sleepover during the week in order for her to take a break from Luna. She seems to be bored with only Molly(the resident dog) to play with, so we know that she's willing to play a little bit. But only on her terms. Advice?

Comment: Personally, I'd let them negotiate this.

Answer (score 2):

Why does this bother you?

Your Newfoundland seems to be able to handle the situation quite well. We have an older and a younger dog too (1 and 3 years) and as long as they don't get too aggressive with each other, we just let them sort it out.
Unless they are in danger of hurting each other, I would not intervene. This is part of their normal social behavior.